# How to go through two loops in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in this code:

```
{% for dayName in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ dayName }}</td>
    {% for value in data.dayName %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**data** is an object containing arrays, for an instance:

> data['Sunday'] = [1 ,2 ,3]

And all what I want to do is create two loops through that object.

I will be thankful for each form of help,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dayName` is a variable not the key itself. `data.dayName` is interpreted as `data['dayName']`, that's why you're not getting the right results.

Instead, you can do:

```
{% for dayName, vals in data.items %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{ dayName }}</td>
     {% for value in vals %}
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
     {% endfor %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know why receiving this error : 'Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 6'. ?

Comment: @Vba_Beg Is it related to the current problem with a similar dataset?

Comment: it's related to current problem

Comment: @Vba_Beg I don't see where the problem could possibly be coming from with the code I've provided.